# Aggregate by timestamp and Sum by float

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a set of data in mongoDB that I have to sum up grouped by `$timestamp`. I succeeded in grouping them day by day, but now I need to sum them by another field.

Example data:

```
[
    {
        _id: "1442",
        timestamp: "1458080642000",
        iden: "15",
        scores_today: "0.000000",
        scores_total: "52337.000000"
    }
]
```

My code

```
var project = {
        "$project":{ 
            "_id" : 0,
            "y": {
                "$year": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0), "$timestamp"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "m": {
                "$month": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0), "$timestamp"
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            "d": {
                "$dayOfMonth": {
                    "$add": [
                        new Date(0), "$timestamp"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "iden" : "$iden",
            "totalTd" : "$scores_today"
            "total" : "$scores_today_total"
        } 
    },
    group = {   
        "$group": { 
            "_id": { 
                "mac" : "$mac",
                "year": "$y", 
                "month": "$m", 
                "day": "$d"
            },  
            count : { "$sum" : "$total"}
            countOther : { "$sum" : "$totalTd" }
        }
    };
    mongoDB.collection('raw').aggregate([ project, group ]).toArray....
```

I'm not able to sum them. What I need to change?
I need to group them day by day (and this **works** ) and by iden ( **works** ) then sum up differents scores.

Comment: Your `"timestamp"` value is a "string". In fact all of the numbers are "strings". The methods you are using only work with numeric values. You need to fix your data first.

Comment: Thanks for this. I fixed it, now they are floating numbers (except timestamp which is an integer)